# save state chrome extension with event pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension I am working on that queries a remote server and shows a desktop notification when it changes.  I am using an event page which will frequently go to sleep so I use a Google Alarm to have it do a check every 5 minutes. I save the last state out into a variable and compare it to current state to determine if a desktop notification should be displayed.  I'm finding this last state variable is frequently going undefined when chrome is not in the foreground or under other conditions.  I have a few variables this may be happening to as well.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Store it in chrome.storage.local and read on start of the event page script, there are many examples.

Comment: Thanks!  I was suspecting I had to use chrome storage.  How does running alarms work, how do I prevent duplicate alarms from starting?  Right now I am not registering any event, I'm just writing the script like it was a JS file and not attached to any chrome listeners.  Is there a listener I should attach to prevent duplicate alarms and so on?